# Why does my do-while loop exit after one iteration?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, while-loop, do-while

Beginner programmer here:

I am trying to format a `do` `while` loop to work in a way that if the user inputs an incorrect number outside the range of 0-4, then my program should ask the user to input a number in the correct range. Once the parameter has been met, I would like my code to continue to run the `if` statements. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int userNum;
    char tableOne[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
    int tableTwo[5] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    printf("Enter a whole number in the range of 0 to 4.\n");
    scanf("%d", &userNum);

    do {
        printf("ERROR. ENTER WHOLE NUMBER \nIN THE RANGE OF 0 - 4 \nIN NUMERICAL FORMAT.\n");
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
        break:
    } while (userNum < 0 || userNum > 4);

    if (userNum == 0) {
        printf("%d", tableOne[0] + tableTwo[0]);
    }
    if (userNum == 1) {
        printf("%d", tableOne[1] + tableTwo[1]);
    }
    if (userNum == 2) {
        printf("%d", tableOne[2] + tableTwo[2]);
    }
    if (userNum == 3) {
        printf("%d", tableOne[3] + tableTwo[3]);
    }
    if (userNum == 4) {
        printf("%d", tableOne[4] + tableTwo[4]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: I suggest you read the whole line *as text* (with e.g. `fgets`). Then use `sscanf` or `strtol` to convert it to a number, with validation. If you use `sscanf` remember to check what it [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value). This way it will be easier to discard non-numeric input, which your current system have a problem with.

Comment: `break:` Did this actually compile? Please post the actual code by using copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

1. `break` statement after the `scanf` exits the loop immediately and it does not even reach the `while` condition check. Remove it
2. Check the result of `scanf` to see if the number was read correctly:

   ```
   if(scanf ("%d", &userNum) != 1) {/* do something as user input was incorrect */}
   ```
3. You do not need those `if`s as well (`break` is not needed too - you should read in your exercise book or ask your teacher what this statement does):

   ```
   printf("%d", tableOne [userNum] + tableTwo [userNum]);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement exits the loop immediately after the `scanf()`. This explains your observation: the loop exits after 1 iteration. It actually exits during the first iteration, before the validation test.

Note that you should check for conversion errors, consume the offending input and restart the input in case `scanf()` does not return `1` and report the end of file if no more input is available.

A `do { ... } while` loop is inappropriate to combine both forms of input validation because the validity test is meaningless if there was a conversion error and it cannot be bypassed with a `continue` statement.  `do { ... } while` loops are rarely the right tool and tend to embed logic errors, such as missing conditions. You should use a `for (;;)` loop (aka *for ever* loop) and write the conditions explicitly.

Using a combination of `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead of `scanf()` allows for better error handling and recovery.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int userNum;
    char tableOne[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
    int tableTwo[5] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    for (;; printf("Try again: ")) {
        char buf[80];
        int offset = 0;

        printf("Enter a whole number in the range of 0 to 4: ");

        // read input from the user
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            printf("Missing input: unexpected end of file. Aborting.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // attempt to convert the input as an integer
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d %n", &userNum, &offset) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input: not a number.\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (userNum >= 0 && userNum <= 4) {
            // value is invalid
            printf("Error: value must be in range 0 to 4: %d.\n", userNum);
            continue;
        }
        // input was successful and value is correct, check for extra input
        if (buf[offset] != '\0') {
            // this should be considered an error, for example if the user
            // typed 1.2, the extra input ".2" is definitely an error.
            printf("Extra characters: %s\n", buf + offset);
            continue;
        }
        // input was successful and value is in the expected range.
        break;
    }

    // note that the code below can be replaced with a single statement
    // printf("%d\n", tableOne[userNum] + tableTwo[userNum]);

    if (userNum == 0) {
        printf("%d\n", tableOne[0] + tableTwo[0]);
    }
    if (userNum == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", tableOne[1] + tableTwo[1]);
    }
    if (userNum == 2) {
        printf("%d\n", tableOne[2] + tableTwo[2]);
    }
    if (userNum == 3) {
        printf("%d\n", tableOne[3] + tableTwo[3]);
    }
    if (userNum == 4) {
        printf("%d\n", tableOne[4] + tableTwo[4]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

i think you need something like this. where you need to put{} on the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int userNum;

char tableOne [5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};

int tableTwo [5] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

printf ("Enter a whole number in the range of 0 to 4.\n");

do {
 scanf("%d", &userNum);
 printf("ERROR. ENTER WHOLE NUMBER \nIN THE RANGE OF 0-4 \nIN NUMERICAL FORMAT.\n");     scanf("%d", &userNum);
}
while (userNum < 0 || userNum > 4){

if (userNum == 0){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [0] + tableTwo [0]); 
    break;
}

if (userNum == 1){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [1] + tableTwo [1]);
    break;
}

if (userNum == 2){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [2] + tableTwo [2]);
    break;
}

if (userNum == 3){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [3] + tableTwo [3]);
    break;
}

if (userNum == 4){
    printf("%d", tableOne [4] + tableTwo [4]);
    break;
}

return 0;
 }
}
```

**edit**

So, for now i understand that your do while loop have some issues.
Because print the printf and is not doing the if' statement.
I will search something to give some decent code.

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main() {

 int userNum;

char tableOne [5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};

int tableTwo [5] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

printf ("Enter a whole number in the range of 0 to 4.\n");
scanf("%d", &userNum);

if (userNum < 0 || userNum > 4){
  do {
   printf("ERROR. ENTER WHOLE NUMBER IN THE RANGE OF 0-4 \nIN NUMERICAL FORMAT.\n");     
   scanf("%d", &userNum);
  }
  while (userNum < 0 || userNum > 4);
}

if (userNum == 0){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [0] ); 
}

if (userNum == 1){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [1] + tableTwo [1]);
}

if (userNum == 2){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [2] + tableTwo [2]);
}

if (userNum == 3){ 
    printf("%d", tableOne [3] + tableTwo [3]);
}

if (userNum == 4){
    printf("%d", tableOne [4] + tableTwo [4]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is the difference between this code, and the one in the image in the question? What difference does it make? Why does it solve the OP's problems? Please [read about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh *now* I see what you did. It's wrong, and will result in build errors. You seem to have misunderstood the OP's code. And you seem to have a basic misunderstanding about the loop statements in C.

Comment: now you made me see it. i will edit and think more about it. thanks for the info